# Using another class as vector in a composite class

Tags: c++, class, vector, composite

I have 2 classes, they have a composite relationship. How do I include the class as a vector in another class? Can anyone tell me how to initialize the vector as well?

```
class Student{
int id;
string name;
public:
 Student(int id = 0, string name = "NA")
: id(id), name(name) {}
int getId() {return id;}
string getName() {return name;}
};

class Faculty{
int id;
string name;
vector<Student> student;
public:
 Faculty(int id = 0, string name = "NA", vector<Student> student)
 {
 id = id;
 name = name;
 student = student;
}
int getId() {return id;}
string getName() {return name;}
};
```

Comment: What is `attraction`?

Comment: sorry, it's a typo..

Comment: Try giving parameters to member functions (constructors in your case) and members different names.   Do you honestly expect a statement of the form `id = id` to set one object to equal to another?   Also, to use a vector `#include <vector>` is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use the same identifier for both your data members and your constructor parameters, you will need to initialize them with an initialization list-- not in the function body.

```
class Faculty{
  int id;
  string name;
  vector<Student> student;

   public:
   Faculty(int id = 0, string name = "NA", vector<Student> student={})
   : id(id)
   ,name(name)
   ,student(student)
   {}
};
```

You can provide a default parameter for the vector with an empty initialization list.

If you are only going to give *some* of your parameters default values, they must come after your parameters that do not have a defaults specified.  This is why your example code would fail to compile.